# transfering a transform variable between two scritps in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, public, transfer

```
    public class player_movement : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    public Transform position;
    void Start()
    {
        position = GetComponent<Transform>();
    }
```

how do I acsess the position variable in another script

Comment: Use position.Position

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason for any of this at all.

Your component `player_movement` is of type [`MonoBehaviour`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.html) which is a [`Behaviour`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Behaviour.html) which is a [`Component`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component.html) and therefore already **has** the inherited property [`transform`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component-transform.html) returning the `Transform` reference if the `GameObject` your component is attached to.

So whoever has a reference to your component immediately also has access to its `.transform.position` anyway.

---

As to how get that reference, there are thousands of different ways. The most typical ones

```
public player_movement playerMovement;
```

simply drag and drop it in vis the Inspector.

On another component attached to the same `GameObject` use

```
var playerMovement = GetComponent<player_movement>();
```

or if there is only one in the scene anyway

```
var playerMovement = FindObjectOfType<player_movement>();
```

either way in the end as said you can simply use

```
var playerTransform = playerMovement.transform;
```

and do with it whatever you want like accessing its position

```
var playerPosition = playerTransform.position;
```